# Submit ASP.NET CORE MVC Quiz/Exam with different type of choices

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm working on Online Quiz System.

My models:

EXAM.cs

```
    public Exam()
    {
        this.Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int QuestionsCount { get; set; }
```

Question.cs

```
public Question()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            this.Choices = new HashSet<Choice>();
        }

        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Choice> Choices { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ExamId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(ExamId))]
        public Exam Exam { get; set; }
```

Choice.cs

```
public Choice()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string QuestionId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(QuestionId))]
        public Question Question { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool IsTrue { get; set; }
```

Answer.cs

```
public Answer()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ChoiceId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(ChoiceId))]
        public Choice Choice { get; set; }
```

Each question can have many answers. Every answer can be true or false. If a question has more than one answer that is true, then i use checkboxes (multiple choice), in other case i use radiobuttons (single choice).

Take.cshtml - Exam View

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        @foreach (var q in Model.Questions)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="box-header">
                            <h3 class="box-title">@(counter +". "+q.Text)</h3>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-header -->
                        <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
                            <table class="table table-hover">
                                @{
                                    var trueChoices = q.Choices.Where(c => c.IsTrue == true).Count();
                                    var order = Model.AnswersOrder;
                                    var currentChoices = q.Choices;
                                }
                                @if (order == OrderType.Fixed)
                                {
                                    currentChoices = currentChoices.OrderBy(c => c.CreatedOn).ToList();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    currentChoices = examService.GetMixedChoices(currentChoices);
                                }
                                @foreach (var choice in currentChoices)
                                {

                                 <tr>
                                        @if (trueChoices <= 1)
                                        {
                                            <td class="col-xs-2"><input name='asd' value='asd' type="radio" /></td>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <td class="col-xs-2"><input name="asd" value='asd' type="checkbox" /></td>
                                        }
                                        <td class="col-xs-8">@choice.Text</td>
                                    </tr>



                                }
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box -->
                </div>
            </div>

            counter++;

        }

        <div class="box-footer">
            <button id="submitExam" type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My question is how can i submit this form? I want to put the information in one table with user id and choice id and to check if the selected choice is correct or not.

Thank you!

Comment: `put the information in one table with user id and choice id` For posting expected data, you can try to iterate over `<div class="row">` to dynamically generate data in javascript client side code logic, then post data to back-end service via Ajax etc. Besides, you may need to post user id and each question id with choice id (rather than just user id and choice id).

Comment: `check if the selected choice is correct or not` After you get user posted data in your action method, valid selected choice of corresponding question in custom code logic based on your actual requirement.